# Cannot override default postgres password in Airflow helm chart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I'mtrying to override default password for `postgres` users when deploying Airflow with helm but for some reason, it does not work and password is still `postgres`.
I'm using 1.8.0 chart of Airflow.
My postgresql part in values.yaml for Airflow looks like that:

```
global:
  postgresql:
    postgresqlUsername: postgres
    existingSecret: airflow-postgresql-secret

postgresql:
  auth:
    enablePostgresUser: true
    username: postgres
    postgresPassword: ""
    password: ""
    existingSecret: airflow-postgresql-secret
```

My secret looks like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: airflow-postgresql
data:
  postgres-password: {{ .Values.postgres.postgresPassword| b64enc | quote }}
type: Opaque
```

I've later run describe on postgres and saw that it refers to the `postgres-password` key in `airflow-postgresql` secret. I was trying to change the name of my secret and key but it did not worked.

```
❯ kubectl describe pod airflow-postgresql-0 -n airflow-sandbox
Name:             airflow-postgresql-0
Namespace:        airflow-sandbox
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             aks-dev-21245326-vmss000000/10.92.169.4
Start Time:       Thu, 13 Apr 2023 16:41:40 +0200
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/component=primary
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=airflow
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql
                  controller-revision-hash=airflow-postgresql-78588bb7f9
                  helm.sh/chart=postgresql-12.1.9
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=airflow-postgresql-0
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.0.222
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.0.222
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/airflow-postgresql
Containers:
  postgresql:
    Container ID:   containerd://718bcc7688e397f13926621b4280bc4c44ddb5af623f5cb942a29951dd367287
    Image:          docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11
    Image ID:       docker.io/bitnami/postgresql@sha256:7ec0c3f45448491d0b8bee2a8542b7aba988bb7ebdc24fd6c9466e894356816d
    Port:           5432/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 13 Apr 2023 16:41:53 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      250m
      memory:   256Mi
    Liveness:   exec [/bin/sh -c exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:  exec [/bin/sh -c -e exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
[ -f /opt/bitnami/postgresql/tmp/.initialized ] || [ -f /bitnami/postgresql/.initialized ]
] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG:                        false
      POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER:               5432
      POSTGRESQL_VOLUME_DIR:                /bitnami/postgresql
      PGDATA:                               /bitnami/postgresql/data
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:                    <set to the key 'postgres-password' in secret 'airflow-postgresql'>  Optional: false
      POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_LDAP:               no
      POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_TLS:                no
      POSTGRESQL_LOG_HOSTNAME:              false
      POSTGRESQL_LOG_CONNECTIONS:           false
      POSTGRESQL_LOG_DISCONNECTIONS:        false
      POSTGRESQL_PGAUDIT_LOG_CATALOG:       off
      POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES:       error
      POSTGRESQL_SHARED_PRELOAD_LIBRARIES:  pgaudit
```

I've later added `createSecret: false`
and when describing the pod, I can see now that it refers to my secret:
`POSTGRES_PASSWORD:                    <set to the key 'postgres-password' in secret 'airflow-postgresql-secret'>  Optional: false`

but it still accept `postgres` as a password and not the password I store in the secretKey

```
❯ kubectl describe secret airflow-postgresql-secret -n airflow-sandbox
Name:         airflow-postgresql-secret
Namespace:    airflow-sandbox
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: airflow
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: airflow-sandbox

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
postgres-password:  16 bytes
```